# Combine nested list and find order

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, numpy

I have a nested list like this:

```
[
 [
  [0.08, 0.34,0.68],
  [0.20, 0.5,  0.92, 0.96],
  [0.23, 0.52, 0.88, 0.91],
  [inf]
 ],
 [
  [0.60],
  [inf],
  [inf],
  [0.05, 0.70, 0.79, 0.89]
 ]
]
```

The size of one level down is fixed **7x2** for example. But the bottom most level is variable.

I want to create a sorted combined list like this

```
[0.05,0.08,0.20,0.23,0.34,...]
```

but I also want the list the number belongs to for example *0.05* belongs to *[1,3]* and so on.

Can anyone help me with this? I can combine this into a sorted list. But I cannot find an efficient way to get the list index.

Comment: Explain how `0.05` *belongs* to `[1, 3]`... you mean it's at index `[1][3]`?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from numpy import inf
lst = [[[0.08, 0.34,0.68],[0.20, 0.5, 0.92, 0.96], [0.23, 0.52, 0.88, 0.91], [inf]], [[0.60], [inf], [inf],[0.05, 0.70, 0.79, 0.89]]]

sorted((e, i, j) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in range(len(lst[0])) for e in lst[i][j])

# [(0.05, 1, 3),
#  (0.08, 0, 0),
#  (0.2, 0, 1),
#  (0.23, 0, 2),
#  (0.34, 0, 0),
#  (0.5, 0, 1),
# ...
```

You can unpack the index from the values using `zip`:

```
vals, *inds = zip(*sorted((e, i, j) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in range(len(lst[0])) for e in lst[i][j]))

vals
# (0.05, 0.08, 0.2, 0.23, 0.34, 0.5, 0.52, 0.6, 0.68, 0.7, 0.79, 0.88, 0.89, 0.91, 0.92, 0.96, inf, inf, inf)

inds
# [(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
#  (3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively parse lists  nested to any depth doing something like:

```
def nested_list_walker(nested_lists, prefix=()):
    """Yields item, nested_index pairs."""
    try:
        for index, nested_list in enumerate(nested_lists):
            for output in nested_list_walker(nested_list,
                                             prefix=prefix + (index,)):
                yield output
    except TypeError:
        yield nested_lists, prefix
```

On your example, sorting this generator yields:

```
[(0.08, (0, 0, 0)),
 (0.2, (0, 1, 0)),
 (0.23, (0, 2, 0)),
 (0.34, (0, 0, 1)),
 (0.5, (0, 1, 1)),
 (0.52, (0, 2, 1)),
 (0.6, (1, 0, 0)),
 (0.68, (0, 0, 2)),
 (0.7, (1, 3, 1)),
 (0.79, (1, 3, 2)),
 (0.88, (0, 2, 2)),
 (0.89, (1, 3, 3)),
 (0.91, (0, 2, 3)),
 (0.92, (0, 1, 2)),
 (0.96, (0, 1, 3)),
 (inf, (0, 3, 0)),
 (inf, (1, 1, 0)),
 (inf, (1, 2, 0))]
```